# Unable to start a sub activity using intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to start a sub activity from a Main activity using intents using Android SDK version 4. Doing so, results in an error during runtime.

Screen Error received from the emulator - "Unfortunately MyFirstApp has stopped"

LogCat error - "Could not find class 'com.example.firstapp.DisplayMessageActivity', referenced from method com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.sendMessage"

Here "com.example.firstapp.DisplayMessageActivity" is the sub activity called from the main activity "com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"

**Same file content:**

**com.example.firstapp.MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**com.example.firstapp.DisplayMessageActivity**

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);

        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() { }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_message,
                      container, false);
              return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.firstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

PS: I was trying to follow the tutorial content from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

-Deep

Comment: please Add your locat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest you have the activity named : android:name="com.example.**myfirstapp**.DisplayMessageActivity"

Actually the package name is : com.example.**firstapp**

So your Manifest must declasre the activity as:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.firstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

Silly but frustrating error. Hope you learn to focus from this mistake.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the mistake. I have made the changes but still the same issue persists. This time though with a different error.

Error occurs at this line 

Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);

of the Main Activity class.

Error details:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.firstapp.DisplayMessageActivity
at com.example.firstapp.MainActivity.sendMessage(MainActivity.java:70)
... 14 more

Comment: @Deepan You are getting ClassDef Not found error because your  class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity. The problem is that the class ActionBarActivity is somehow not being recognized. Check your project dependencies.

Comment: Thank you Eu.Dr. I have replaced to extend Activity and its working as expected now. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

It may be because you renamed the package.

You're main activity is inside

com.example.myfirstapp,

Your sub activity is identified in your manifest to be in

com.example.firstapp

Note the missing 'my'.